# How to autologin in ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-server, autologin

I am flashing ubuntu server on system through automation i.e. which includes preseed file.
I need to autologin user once ubuntu server is installed.

I have tried approach mentioned in this link https://askubuntu.com/a/819154/863211. It works if I enter manually but the same is not working when I add commands in preseed file.

I expect to autologin user once ubuntu server installation finishes using preseed file

Comment: You should ask this on AskUbuntu, since this is not a programming question

Answer (score -1):

Resolved this by adding script which contains the same logic as mentioned in above link. This script is then called in preseed file.

Comment: What do you mean by 'called in a preseed file?'

Comment: Added the logic in preseed file (answer file)

Comment: This does not answer the question

Comment: Please explain in further detail. Thank you